# How to identify the current position in a file while reading a hex file(.dat) in python?

Tags: python-3.x, byte, file-read, hex-editors

I am doing a project in which I have to read `.dat file` and extract the necessary values from it. I need to automate the complete process, i.e on a single click I want all the necessary values from that `.dat` file. The searching process for it is bit complex.

Right now all I want is some way I can create a function with the help of which I can get the current position up to which I have read the number of bytes. For example: if a call  function through which I am reading the first 8 byte from a `.dat` file then I want a function which will tell me the current position (i.e. like a counter which keeps a check of number of bytes I have read in total).

If I call three functions in which first function read 8 bytes, second function 4 bytes and third function again 8 bytes, then I want some method through which I will be able to get the current position, in this case 8+4+8=20.

I hope you understand my concern.

```
routeHead_len=8
def readDAT(filename):
    with open(filename,'rb') as f:
        global data
        data=f.read()
    return data

def readRouteHead():                            
    route_Head=[]
    for i in range(routeHead_len):
        route_Head.append(data[i])
    return route_Head
```

Comment: seek and tell should be enough. just call it on an opened file object

Comment: @bigdataolddriver but sir i want current position up to the bytes i have read..

Answer (score 3):

a sneaky way is work around by bytesio
and benefit from the io  function family

```
import io
allData = open("/bin/bash",'rb').read()
fp = io.BytesIO(allData)
print("before {}, length {} after {}".format(fp.tell(), len(fp.read(8)),fp.tell()))
print("before {}, length {} after {}".format(fp.tell(), len(fp.read(4)),fp.tell()))
print("before {}, length {} after {}".format(fp.tell(), len(fp.read(8)),fp.tell()))

output:
before 0, length 8 after 8
before 8, length 4 after 12
before 12, length 8 after 20
```

Comment: yes sir it will be very difficult..i called readDAT function(which will read the complete file and store it in the buffer named 'data') after that i am extracting values through data using for loops..but as per your method i will not be able to do so..i need to read dat file in segments..means i have to read first 8 bytes then 4 bytes then n*4 bytes(here n is dynamic) and so on..so what will be best way to do so..